# Take a screenshot without Python console window showing

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

This runs okay, but, when I run it, the screenshot includes also the python.exe window which pops up while running the code. I don't want the window to be in the screenshot. Any suggestions?

```
img = pyautogui.screenshot('Screenshot.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you change your filename extension to .Pyw

screenshot.pyw for example

What is a PYW file?

The PYW file type is primarily associated with Python by Python Software Foundation. PYW files are used in Windows to indicate a script needs to be run using PYTHONW.EXE instead of PYTHON.EXE in order to prevent a DOS console from popping up to display the output. This patch makes it possible to import such scripts, in case they're also usable as modules.

Comment: Can I know, if I wanted to wait until a certain window is opened to take the screenshot, what would help?

Comment: any time ! my pleasure

Comment: what window ? you can always use time.sleep() to wait a lil bit for the window to open, or if it is callable through a command Line, you can use os python module to open it yourself

Comment: or, if you know the name of the process related to the window you try to screenshot you write this


{p = Sys.WaitProcess("Name of the process")
 if p.Exists:
  img = pyautogui.screenshot('Screenshot.png')

Answer (score -1):

`sleep` before screenshot, and minimize the python window during sleep.